# Gatsbyjs _ Redux - How to provide a global store to a Gatsby's project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store, gatsby

I'm working with Gatsby.js and Redux, I'm trying to provide a global store to my project, how do that ? I have searched the documentation but so far there is nothing very straightforward to install Redux, and I don't see any parts in the project where I can provide the store globally in a simple way like :

file.js :

```
< element store={store}> 
    <SubElement/>
</element>
```

Someone have an hint maybe, would be great,
Thanks

Comment: There's an official example on how to use Redux with Gatsby: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux

Comment: works like a charm

Comment: There's unfortunately no explanation in the official gatsby docs about this (yet). https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-storage-redux/. But Gatsby actually uses Redux internally. I guess the example in Fabian's link maybe exposes the existing redux store which is used both client side and for ssr builds in Gatsby?